# Boost shared pointer initialization

Tags: c++, pointers, shared

I am pretty a beginner in C++. I have following problem. In the class MevisPatientModel I defined:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<egMevisPatientModel> Ptr_t;
```

Then I "defined" the variable:

```
egMevisPatientModel::Ptr_t v_PatientModel;
```

Now when I try to access the getType function of the class MevisPatientModel :

```
v_PatientModel->getType()
```

...I'm getting following message:

> Assertion failed! ...shared_ptr.hpp Expression px!= 0

My intention is that the pointer wasn't initialized. Now I know that here are many answers which would "fit" to my question. But as I said, I am a beginner. To be honest I don't these answers understand. Please help me and give me a clear and specific answer to my problem. Thank you very much.

Greets, Marco

Comment: "My intention is that the pointer wasn't initialized." - what do you mean by this? Do you mean you expected it to be "NULL" or do you mean that you expected there to be a valid object in the pointer?

Comment: You have defined the pointer variable which points to nothing. You have to define the object as well and make the pointer point to the object

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an dynamic object with `new` and assign the resulting pointer into the `shared_ptr`:

```
egMevisPatientModel::Ptr_t v_PatientModel(
    std::make_shared<egMevisPatientModel>());
```

Comment: Its recommended to use make_shared
`egMevisPatientModel::Ptr_t v_PatientModel = make_shared<egMevisPatientModel>()`

Comment: Technically it doesn't need to be a heap allocated object. You can also just use a pointer to an automatic object with a "do nothing" deleter.

Comment: @pmr: In that case what would be the point of using a `shared_ptr`?

Comment: Sometimes just to work with some weird API or to manage resources other than memory.