# Are initialization lists a better way of instantiating boost::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, initialization-list

I have a pretty large application which uses a number of threads(boost), opencv, opengl and qt.

I started getting a problem with one of the boost::shared_ptr<> objects.

In certain executions of the application, not always, the boost::shared_ptr pointer used to point to an invalid location resulting in an UnhandledException reading that location.

Owing to the fact that this behaviour was not consistent, my guess was that somehow there was a problem with the boost::shared_ptr initialization.

A comment in this post: [Boost shared pointer initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259740/boost-shared-pointer-initialization) suggests that initialization lists are the recommended way for initializing boost::shared_ptr. Boost's documentation also says that make_shared is faster and exception safe. I am using Boost 1.53.0.

Following that guideline, I removed the initialization from the constructor:

```
FrameObject::FrameObject(){
//initialization code
_contour = boost::make_shared<Contour>(); //Contour is a user defined object encapsulating a CvSeq* pointer.
```

and used initialization list instead:

```
FrameObject::FrameObject():
_contour(boost::make_shared<Contour>()){
//other initialization code
}
```

<strike>As for now, using initialization lists has apparently solved my problem
. But since the UnhandledException was not being raised always, I am not really sure if using initialization lists has indeed solved my problem.</strike>
EDIT: It hasn't solved the problem. The exception did eventually crop up.

Comment: You should always use member initialisation lists. It is not about shared_ptr. Your problem here is definitely unrelated.

Comment: Most likely, you don't manage the object lifetime solely by `shared_ptr`'s - I guess there're places in the code where you attempt to `delete` this object manually. This is the most probable way to make `shared_ptr` point to an invalid instance.

Comment: No I am not doing that. I do not delete the contour object(see code above) at any instance. But again, the application is a bit old and the previous developer has kept no documentation (except for the few comments here and there), so I'll have to dig into the nooks and recesses and see if there's actually a delete against the shared_ptr. But I am fairly certain there isn't. Thanks for the pointer though! :P